# How do I create a DiscordChannel entity in DSharp+ with no context

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I want to make my Discord bot send a message on startup using the Discord Message Builder, but .sendAsync() requires a DiscordChannel entity. All the guides I've read use context, but I can't use context unless I'm replying to a message, which I can't do.

```
static async Task Send(string text)
            {
                var msg = await new DiscordMessageBuilder()
                .WithContent(text)
                .SendAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by startup but I wrote a solution that works when the bot should send a message when it joins a server.

At first your Bot needs a special intent which you can add in your DiscordConfiguration

```
Intents = DiscordIntents.Guilds
```

After this step you can create a eventhandler which fires when your bot joins a guild. The eventarguments provides the guild and you can get the default channel of the server.

EventHandler:

```
Client.GuildCreated += OnGuildCreated;
```

EventFunction:

```
private void OnGuildCreated(object sender, GuildCreateEventArgs e)
    {
        DiscordChannel defaultChannel =  e.Guild.GetDefaultChannel();
        defaultChannel.SendMessageAsync("Your text / message");
    }
```

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Edit:
The solution only shows how to get channels. If the default channel can't/shouldn't be taken, you can also use Guild.Channels to get all channels of a server.